# Number of Geometry Shader Executions?

Tags: graphics, pixel-shader, vertex-shader, geometry-shader

So a vertex shader is executed for each vertex and a fragment shader for each fragment (right?).

How many times is a geometry shader executed?

Comment: Not to nitpick but it's a "fragment shader", not a "pixel shader".  A fragment has things a pixel doesn't, namely: depth.  There can be a lot of fragments that each map to the same pixel x/y.  Lots of people call it a "pixel shader" but even if you're going to do so, it's incorrect to say a pixel shader is executed once for each pixel because, in fact, it can be executed more than once for each pixel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's executed once for each primitive (triangle, line or point) after the vertex shader has transformed the constituent vertices.

Comment: aha thanks, so let's say i render a quad using GL_QUADS in openGL, is it executed twice?

Comment: I think it would be executed once - the quad is a single primitive (even if it might be rasterised as triangles underneath).

Comment: Geometry shaders can only receive: Point, Line, Line with Adjacency, Triangle, Triangle with Adjacency.  So it would be called twice with Quads because it's already broken down into triangles when it reaches the geometry shader

Comment: @colithium right, the geometry shader would receive triangles.  Just for predictability I imagine it would be better to stick to triangles further up the pipeline.